# At which frequency run CTXSYS.CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX(...) on a fulltext index?

Tags: oracle, index, optimization, full-text-search

I've been told to run *periodically* `CTXSYS.CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX(...)` on some fulltext indexes, with no more information, in particular at which frequency this task should be run.

I guess that it depends on the amount of indexed data, the time after which the index does not "performs well" (maybe after a lot of writes), the time taken by running  `CTXSYS.CTX_DDL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX(...)` (is it "blocking" DB when running?), etc. so the answer to this question may not be very precise.

However, I would like to know if there are some general rules, principles, recommendations to follow (couldn't find any).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the index statistics report by first enabling reporting on the index  (`BEGIN ctx_output.enable_query_stats(ix_my_indexname); END;`).  Then you can use the procedure `ctx_report.index_stats`.  While sifting through the CLOB of info in the report, the most useful information to me is the FRAGMENTATION STATISTICS...estimated row fragmentation: 23%

see Oracle documentation here for more thorough [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/coutpkg.htm#CCREF2127) of the stats report.